How can I know if a widget fits into my layout?
Lets say I have a complex widget build of a widget tree which takes up some space. Now, when the available space is smaller than this widgets size, it shall be replaced by a simpler version.
Everyone is talking about how to find the available space. But how do I know the required space? How do I know the size of a widget in advance? Are you all guessing this in your responsive designs?

you can get the children sizes when using CustomMultiChildLayout or Flow widgets - all done in the "delegate" classes

For the ultimate "give me manual control over layout", look at package:boxy (https://boxy.wiki/).

Let me tell you that the available space can be measure or calculate by using Layout builder and Media Query. These can help to know the screen size of your device.
Required Space, which means the widget that develop and occupied some screen space in your device screen. This can be decided by developers like 20 pixel height or width, 20% of screen space. This is how you can decide the required space for the widget in advance. It completely choice of developer based on available space or device screen.
